# iptables default rules understanding

Tags: iptables

What does the last part in the following rules means in term of traffic that is allowed in (dtp:domain, bootps) ? From my research I understand that bootps is bootstrap and dpt is destination port but I don't get what its actually doing or allowing and I doubt its allowing any packets in, as such default rules wouldn't make sense. (I looked in the man page for iptables but couldn't find the answer)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted the output of `iptables -S`.

Comment: You can also pass the `-n` (numeric) option to `iptables`. Otherwise, ports and IP addresses are resolved to service names and host names, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules allow receiving UDP and TCP packets which were sent to ports 53 (named "domain"; the DNS port) and 67 (named "bootps"; the DHCP & BOOTP server port).

The names are from `/etc/services`, which itself comes from the master list maintained by IANA. These days "bootps" means DHCP, which is an improved form of the old BOOTP protocol.

In short, the rules were meant to allow the system to act as a DNS & DHCP server.

---

Side note 1: The 4th rule is somewhat useless, since DHCP/BOOTP *never* uses TCP. Whoever wrote the ruleset didn't care much.

---

Side note 2: In fact, note that the chain has "policy ACCEPT", which basically means that there's an implicit "accept anything" rule at the very bottom.

Since there are no rules that would reject or drop any packets, then *all* packets will be accepted, making all four rules redundant.

Comment: "In short, the rules were meant to allow the system to act as a DNS & DHCP server." ; do you mean "DNS & DHCP *client*" as these are `INPUT` rules?

Comment: sxc731, no, not a client - you have your `INPUT` and `OUTPUT`s mixed up. `INPUT` = incoming rule.

Answer (score 2):

The services "domain" and "bootps" are listed in /etc/services

Try `grep 'domain' /etc/services` to get the port number for the service.

Or `iptables -nL` to list your rules with port numbers instead of service name.